# Verbs to describe how light moves

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a sentence where pale gray morning light is being viewed through window blinds. I'm trying to think of a way to describe its entrance without sounding cliché. What are some good verbs to use for how light moves?

Comment: There really aren't any, except _shine_ and its ilk, which refers to bright light as a phenomenon attracting and distracting vision. Normally, languages take light and air and gravity for granted and save lexical entries for the things they determine, like _visible, dim, wind, up/down_. Of course, there's always metaphor, and that's what we resort to when the words fail.

Comment: You may want to narrow this down by showing some of your own attempts. Otherwise this is too broad and is a request for creative writing assistance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for writing advice. Try Writers.SE.

Comment: 'Tis but the pale reflex of Cynthia's brow.

Comment: Maybe: "The light of gloaming plodded into the room like a gut-shot sloth looking to down one last beer before its inevitable demise."

Answer (score 2):

The verb **shift** in one of its forms might be suitable.  "Shifting light", "the light shifted", ...

You could also use **wove** or **weaved**, as in "As the light gently wove its way through the blinds ..."

Answer (score 1):

The word **glint** is is nice and pithy. Light also could **[gleam or glare](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Defence_of_Fort_M%27Henry_broadside.jpg)**, **sparkle**, **glimmer**, or **shimmer**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**[permeate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/permeate)** might fit.

> *v.* ~ to pass into or through every part of: *sunshine permeating the room*

**Example:** The morning light permeated the room through the window blinds.

Answer (score 1):

The early pale morning light **[spilled](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22morning+light+spilled%22&oq=%22morning+light+spilled%22&gs_l=serp.12...6721.17577.0.19367.10.10.0.0.0.0.161.1204.1j9.10.0....0...1c.1.37.serp..7.3.412.EgftXaFZQrE)** into the room
 The early pale morning light **[filtered](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22morning%20light%20filtered%22&oq=%22morning%20light%20filtered%22&gs_l=serp.12...10833.14806.0.16612.8.6.0.0.0.1.237.802.3j2j1.6.0....0...1c.1.37.serp..7.1.100.GLJ-nsWOw0w)** into the room
 The early pale morning light **[slipped](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22morning%20light%20slipped%22&oq=%22morning%20light%20slipped%22&gs_l=serp.3...39100.44033.0.45035.15.15.0.0.0.0.147.1487.9j6.15.0....0...1c.1.37.serp..11.4.437.jSHaR3M-5jc)** through the blinds

*Morning light spilled* has 2,010 results in Google books. *Morning light filtered* earns a respectable 13,200 results, whereas *morning light slipped* gains only 264 results. If the OP is looking for an expression which is not clichéd, *slipped* is a worthy candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the verb **refract** in your context.

> (of water, air, or glass) make (a ray of light) change direction when
>   it enters at an angle.

Answer (score 0):

Since the light is coming through blinds, the best word is probably *slant*. You might say *The light slanted down through the blinds and made strip patterns on the floor*... or some such thing. That's assuming they're horizontal blinds, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, light also illuminates, radiates, enters, brightens, dapples, floods, trickles, streams, seeps, pours.

Answer (score 0):

The dim light **announced itself** in broad lines that slowly **crawled** down the wall, **inching** nearer to where they slept.

Answer (score 0):

To a physicist, light moves either as a particle or as a wave; but that doesn't really help you much unless you want to use some aquatic metaphor.

You could go all-out with metaphor like Homer with "[Dawn's rosy fingers](http://everything2.com/title/Rosy+fingered+dawn)", but maybe that sort of thing *is* cliché.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
What do spins do?

1. make you dizzy